# VS AppCenter - XCUI - Getting Failed to analyze MachO file error

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, xcuitest

I am creating an azure Devops pipeline for UI testing my iOS application.

I have built my project and feeding my ipa to Visual Studio AppCenter Test pipeline, I was getting the error,

```
Error: Failed to analyze MachO file: Unknown load command: 2147483700
```

I tried to run my code manually using appcenter-cli from terminal and still getting the same error. I saw this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/issues/1165) in GitHub and not sure how to do this workaround in devops pipeline.

Am I missing something here? Can no-one use AppCenter CLI because of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your app with xcode 11 and than it works. But this is just a workaround. Hopefully they will fix it in the near future.

Comment: Yeah, I finally used Xcode 11 for my tests.